# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at MFMessageController

Tags: ios5, exc-bad-access, nszombie, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have got this error when I press send button from the message composer sheet, my piece of code is this:

```
-(void)ComposerSheet 
{
    picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];

}
```

I have initialised the picker in the .h file. How do I get out of here? I tried using NSZombies but as the problem is occurring at the messaging part, I can't use them there.

Comment: Just a note on syntax conventions: method names should start with a lower case letter :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the release of objects, I have commented out all the release objects in my proj. Then it was running well. Then checked where I was doing it wrongly. It worked.

Comment: Commenting out all releases in your code is a sure-fire way to many memory leaks. Consider converting your project to use ARC, then the compiler can help you out with much of the routine memory management.